# Update state via function passed via props

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to update the state via a function that I am passing to the child component via `props` via the onChange attribute. This is in the child component:

```
<input className="minutes" type="number" defaultValue={ this.props.minutes } onChange={ this.props.updatePreferences("minutes", this.value) }/> minutes.
```

Whilst this is the function in the parent component:

```
  updatePreferences = (preferenceName, enteredValue) => {
     switch (preferenceName) {
      case preferenceName === "minutes":
        this.setState({minutes: enteredValue})
        console.log(this.state)
        return
      case preferenceName === "business":
        this.setState({...this.state, interests: {
          ...this.state.interests, business: !this.state.interests.business}})
        return
      default:
        return
    }
  }
```

Which is then passed via the Route to the child:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={props => <Welcome minutes = {this.state.minutes} 
                                                          interests = {this.state.interests}
                                                          sayHello = {this.sayHello} 
                                                          updatePreferences = {this.updatePreferences} />} />
```

Comment: Try changing `onChange={ this.props.updatePreferences("minutes", this.value) }` to `onChange={ () => this.props.updatePreferences("minutes", this.value) }`.

Comment: Thanks but it's not working, not showing anything on the console when I enter

Answer (score 0):

`defaultValue` is only set during mount as is therefore not able to change when a re-render occurs.  (Unless you update using a `ref`).

Also, you don't want to call the `updatePreferences` method when rendering, so you need to `bind` or use an arrow function.

Use `value` prop instead to create a controlled component:

```
<input className="minutes"
       type="number"
       value={ this.props.minutes } onChange={ () => this.props.updatePreferences("minutes", this.value) }/> minutes.
```

Comment: Thanks. Why should I change value?

Comment: `defaultValue` without a `value` creates an uncontrolled component.  Uncontrolled components need their underlying value changed using a `ref` and will not pick up changes to `props` on re-render.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to make it work:

```
(e) => this.props.updatePreferences("minutes", e.target.value)
```

and the syntax of the switch statement was wrong:

```
 switch (preferenceName) {
  case "minutes":
    this.setState({minutes: enteredValue})
    return
  case "business":
    this.setState({...this.state, interests: {
      ...this.state.interests, business: !this.state.interests.business}})
    return
  default:
    return
}
```